# Javascript Parsing error : Unexpected Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting an  error at the function declaration

> Parsing error : Unexpected

Here is my code:

```
class Item extends Component {
    function changeNumberFormat(number, decimals, recursiveCall) { //Parsing error : Unexpected Error
        const decimalPoints = decimals || 2;
        const noOfLakhs = number / 100000;
        let displayStr;
        let isPlural;

        // Rounds off digits to decimalPoints decimal places
        function roundOf(integer) {
            return +integer.toLocaleString(undefined, {
                minimumFractionDigits: decimalPoints,
                maximumFractionDigits: decimalPoints,
            });
        }

        if (noOfLakhs >= 1 && noOfLakhs <= 99) {
            const lakhs = roundOf(noOfLakhs);
            isPlural = lakhs > 1 && !recursiveCall;
            displayStr = `${lakhs} Lakh${isPlural ? 's' : ''}`;
        } else if (noOfLakhs >= 100) {
            const crores = roundOf(noOfLakhs / 100);
            const crorePrefix = crores >= 100000 ? changeNumberFormat(crores, decimals, true) : crores;
            isPlural = crores > 1 && !recursiveCall;
            displayStr = `${crorePrefix} Crore${isPlural ? 's' : ''}`;
        } else {
            displayStr = roundOf(+number);
        }

        return displayStr;
    }
    ...
    }
```

It looks like I am missing something with the syntax. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When declaring a method in a `class` declaration you don't use the `function` keyword.

Comment: If I don't use the function keyword, it says the changeNumberFormat method is not defined.

Comment: When you call the method recursively, you have to us `this.changeNumberFormat()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your function to a method like this way

```
changeNumberFormat(number, decimals, recursiveCall) { ... }
```

or

```
changeNumberFormat = (number, decimals, recursiveCall)=> { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

youa are trying to declare function inside a react component. Better would be to declare it outside the component.